# MySQL INSERT if SELECT COUNT(*) is greater than 1

Tags: mysql, if-statement

I'm trying a MySQL statement, where I need to check of the user credentials are correct; and only if they are correct -- I insert the data

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE uid = 1 AND password = "67^8ax%!") > 0
THEN
INSERT INTO messages (uid, text, time)
VALUES (1, "Hello", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
END IF
```

I have to do both the operations in a single MySQL query due the limitations of my platform.

Any way to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query

Working in MYSQL, thought shouldn't work in MYSQL :P

```
INSERT INTO messages (uid, text, time)
(SELECT 1, "Hello", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FROM users WHERE uid = 1 AND password = "67^8ax%!")
```

Will work if there is only 1 distinct user with the given username and password..

### **[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8fe76/1)**

Comment: There is no need to count(*) as if that particular user is found then only the record will be inserted else not... Check the fiddle I have covered both condition in the fiddle. OP need is that record should be inserted into message table if that particular user exist and my query follows this condition...

Comment: I went and vastly overcomplicated this in my (deleted) answer, totally forgot about INSERT ... SELECT :)

Comment: works!! Thanks. Although, why shouldn't this be working in MySQL? The column data from SELECT can be appropriately used by INSERT. Isn't this by design?

Comment: I thought that if no row satisfies the condition then it will through error but it didn't...